# how to autorun a shell script after boot - OpenWRT

Tags: openwrt, init.d

i just got interested in OpenWRT and want to try somethings.

i'm trying to run a script right after my OpenWRT boots.
here is my script file

customchain.sh

```
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

START=99

start(){
[my custom chains]
}
```

i've placed this script file at `/etc/init.d`

i wonder why this won't work.
if i check at `/etc/rc.d`, i can see `S99customchain.sh -> ../init.d/customchain.sh`

when i manually restart script file at root directory with
`/etc/init.d/customchain.sh`
i can see it applies well when i check via `iptables -L`

but as i said, this won't automatically starts when i (re)boot my OpenWRT system.

authority is already given by using `+x`

i've already tried using `/etc/init.d/customchain enable` and still doesn't work.

also i already checked similar question at here, and it doesn't have any answers.

what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

**1st approach:**
Add commands to `/etc/rc.local`

```
vi /etc/rc.local
```

inside rc.local:

```
# Description of the script
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/my/script.sh || exit 1   # comments
exit 0
```

**2nd approach:** edit your crontab

```
crontab -e
```

add this line:

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

The script will run when the computer starts up.

Comment: so you mean i should do both 1st and 2nd approach?

Comment: anyway,
in my case, since i am using SDK to build, 2nd approach is not an option.

i've tried 1st apporach and still doesn't work

Even if i try 2nd approach at OpenWRT, it doesn't work.

Comment: Exec `sudo chmod a+x /etc/rc.local`, just to be sure it's executable.

Comment: still same. i've done that both at SDK and at OpenWRT system

Comment: You should use one of the approaches, not both. But first, try and run manually your test script without autorun to make sure it actually works (and make this executable as well).

Comment: Then initiate the rc-local service to run script during boot: `sudo systemctl start rc-local`

Comment: i've tried 1st approach.
also tried manually starting. so which means, there is no shell script error.
i've tried like this on root directory ```/etc/ini.d/customchain.sh (re)start```
i'll try the command you told me now

Comment: Just to let you know, this OpenWRT does not support sudo. also does not supports systemctl command